# How to grab rows which contain a dual id reference

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a messages table:

```
messages:
    id(int)
    send_id(int)
    receive_id(int)
```

And I want to be able to select rows from this only when a->b and b->a exist, e.g.:

```
    id     send_id recieve_id
    0,     15,     16
    1,     16,     15
```

So that basically one message has been passed to each person. How would I be able to go about selecting just one of those two rows (either send or receive), and all of those for a specific id.

I want to only return results that have this duality.

My code currently uses a nested `SELECT` and doesn't work at all as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the result by taking advantage MySQL's `LEAST` and `GREATEST` built-in functions.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    messages
WHERE   (LEAST(send_id, recieve_id), GREATEST(send_id, recieve_id), id)       
IN 
(
    SELECT  LEAST(send_id, recieve_id) as x, 
            GREATEST(send_id, recieve_id) as y, 
            MAX(id) msg_ID
    FROM    messages 
    GROUP   BY x, y
);
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/54291/2)
- [MySQL Comparison Operator (*LEAST/GREATEST*)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html)

Comment: This is great, very elegant compared to my attempt. I especially like the LEAST / GREATER idea for this - I knew there had to be a decent solution. Would accept your answer twice if I could. I have to stop thinking of SQL as a simple language and use/contemplate some of these list constructs. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define an additional synthesized column for this. Different alternatives: permanent as an index (fast), temporary if just for a selection once a month or on-the-fly inside the actual query.

Whatever alternative, that column should contain both ids, ordered in a numerical way and concatenated, maybe by some separation character like `-`. Now when you make a uniqueness restriction to that column only one of the two candidates can be entered into the result, the second one is rejected because it would violate that uniqueness rule.

The trick is the ordered concatenation instead of a *normal* combined index that would allow both variants due to the different order of ids.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I implemented JW's answer above which uses a temporary column based on min / max, but this way would have probably worked as well. What do you mean by uniqueness restriction?

Comment: Either declare the column as unique index, then the RDBMS takes care of refusing double entries, or use a `GROUP BY` operand inside a nested `SELECT` statement. Comes out the same. I refer to 'some means to reject double entries' to keep column entries unique.